How to share a chat bot with other users that can see the bot updates
Im using Thingsboard to send alarms to a telegram bot. I have created the bot, with its name and username, I have the TOKEN, and I have the chat id to send updates to the bot.
Now I, as a telegram user, can see the alarms I send to this bot, and tried using the HTML api simulator using the token and chat-id.
How are the next steps now to allow other users to see the bot updates? Because I sent the bot URL and the bot name (both ways) to a friend to access it, he typed /start, and after that time he should have seen another test update I had sent, but he saw nothing....
I'm new to telegram so any help would be appreciated...
Thanks

Ok I think  I got it... I was using the chatbot ID, and now I tried to use the GROUP (where the chatbot has been added as an admin) ID and it seems to be working now

Your question is a bit vague, but I'll try to explain from what I understood.
All Telegram Bots will have a designated username to it, for example @MyIDBot, this username can be used to send the bot to your friends or anyone. The username can also be used as a link like this: https://t.me/MyIDBot to share the bot.
When a user interacts with your bot such as sending /start command or sends a message, your bot will receive an update from Telegram Bot API server. The Bot TOKEN is used to interact with the Bot API Server. So to get the pending updates you can use the /getUpdates method. You can code your bot to process the updates and to respond to incoming messages.
This is the basics.
On your case (from your question, and the comment), I can see with your code you're sending the alarms from ThingsBoard to a group. I'm assuming you haven't coded your bot to respond to individual users as said previously. Now your bot works just as a broadcaster only sending updates to a group. So if your friends also need to see the updates, they should join in the group where the updates are posted. They will not receive messages from your bot as direct messages.
If you want your bot to send new updates to users individually, you code your bot to save their chat_id in your database when the user sends /start (this will be the first update your bot gets from an individual user). Once you have their chat_id just like you send message to the group, use the user's chat_id to send them update message using /sendMessage.
Hope this helps :)

Thanks,. I see. Yes in my case there's no interaction needed with the bot. Some users in the town hall, designated by the major, need to receive an alert in their phone when a town tank goes under a desired level. So I guess this is working as it should now, I created a group called "Alarms -townname-", made it private, added the needed users to the group, added the chat bot to the group as admin, and used the bot token and the group chat-id to compose the message. So for them they receive the message all together in the group, which looks like the bot originalted the pessage, right?  Thanks!
